# How do I check if a event is triggered or when to use keypress versus keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, events, keyboard-events, dom-events

I've added page navigation to the `window` using the [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) event and noticed it's not working on some browsers. If I use [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) in those browsers the event is triggered.

So my question can be solved by knowing either:

1. For most browser compatibility do I use `keyup` or `keypress`? Can I
   use both?
2. How do I test if an event is supported? For example, if I know the
   brower supports keypress I'll add a handler for it. If it supports
   keyup, I'll add a handler for that. I can add the event handler
   dynamically.

**History:**

In ES4 there was a `willTrigger` method but I don't see that method in the DOM.

**Update:**
I found a possible answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#KeyboardEvent_Sequence). It says that in some browsers `keypress` is dispatched where is does not make any distinction when mentioning `keyup`.

Comment: With regard to (1), keyup and keypress don't do the same thing. As far as I'm aware, every browser supports both. Also, ES4 never shipped.

Comment: ES4 didn't ship but some of the features, such as `addEventListener`, were migrated into later versions of JS.

Comment: I'm not getting any `keypress` events in some browsers but from what I've been reading it might be because it's more related to text inputs. Might add handlers for both and then cancel the event propagation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quickly differentiate between keypress and keyup, keyup will fire only once, no matter how long a key is pressed down for , whereas the keypress event can fire multiple times. You can use both (I don't see why not - you'd use them for different things) , and [basic support for the events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) is present cross-browser (although figures for mobile browser support is not fully known).  There are jquery equivalents of both the [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)/ [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) and [.keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) / [onkeypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Hope this helps

Comment: Adding both mostly works. But in Firefox I'm getting both events dispatching. So I'm moving two steps over. I've used stopImmediatePropagation but I realize now that would only work for events with the same event name. So the first event wins. So I'll add both and then remove the handler for the other one.

Comment: Good stuff. Of course there's the key down event also, let's not forget about that, but I think you have it sorted :)